# CSS: SVGs at the navigation menu to change when the tab is selected(active)

Tags: css, svg, menu, css-selectors

My patience is over and need to get some help about the case. 
I'm trying to make it work - when I open tab at the menu, the default svg(black) icon of the chosen tab needs to be replaced by another svg(white).

```
#menu a .main-menu-icon {
display:inline-block;
width:22px;
height:21px;
line-height:40px;    
margin-right:7px;
background: url(/images/digital.svg);
}
__________________________________________________________
#menu .nav-tabs>li>a.menu_digital>.main-menu-icon{
background: url(/images/digital.svg);
}
#menu .nav-tabs>li>a.menu_digital:active>.main-menu-icon {
background: url(/images/digital_white.svg);
}
```

In that case (stupid maybe), the svg changes(to white) only when I directly press and hold on it, after I release the button, no matter that I'm in the tab's page, the default svg(black) goes back.

Thank you. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Can you prodive your html and javascript code ? What do you use for tab

Comment: I cannot use a JS in that case (doesn't depends on me - didn't get an approval to use it; css only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS in your question contains

```
#menu .nav-tabs>li>a.menu_digital:active>.main-menu-icon {
  background: url(/images/digital_white.svg);
}
```

The selector contains `:active` and thus only applies to the menu item while it is pressed. When the intended page is loaded, the clicked menu item will probably have a **class** `active` (depending on the CMS), so you need to add that to your selector list (note the difference `:` vs `.`):

```
#menu .nav-tabs>li>a.menu_digital:active>.main-menu-icon,
#menu .nav-tabs>li>a.menu_digital.active>.main-menu-icon {
  background: url(/images/digital_white.svg);
}
```